# Is there a way in css to clear all font-family + font-size style declarations?

Tags: php, html, css, styles, font-face

I have a page which is a cms/wysiwyg/ms word nightmare.

It pulls many paragraphs of text from a database, some of which have retained ms word's bizarre html tags - including font declarations!!! ahh!

In one sentence I can have things like:

```
<span style="font-family:Verdana">this is some</span>
<span style="font-family:arial">ugly text!</span>
```

I was wondering if there is a way of removing all font-family and font-size styles so they will adapt the master stylesheet css?

I'd prefer to not get into massive preg_replace conditions if I can avoid it.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `style="font-family:'font-name' !important; font-size:'size' !important;"` these will overwrite them.

Comment: @Joy_S: *Override* them. *Overwrite* means something completely different.

Comment: Sorry. didn't notice it. Thanks for correction. @MikeSherrill'Catcall'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CSS:

```
span {
    font-family: initial !important;
    font-size: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was overthinking this and missed the obvious :P

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're getting inline styles in many places, I would add this to the body CSS

```
body {
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
     font-size: 16px !important;
 }
```

If you notice that all of the inline font styling are going on `span`s, you could target spans instead of the body.

I chose these two fonts because they are the "default" fonts for Windows and Mac/iOS. 
Of course you can choose your own font size. The only unfortunate part about this is if you want a different font and font size in other places you'll have to use more `!important`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `!important` rule for this. But you will have to explicitly define each element you want it to go on (or use the universal selector `*`)

http://jsfiddle.net/b8RKm/

```
* { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif !important; }
```